# How to add actionlistener to whole class without assigning it to components individually?

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton, actionlistener

For example, lets say I have 5 JButtons

```
b1 = new JButton("Add");
b2 = new JButton("Add 2");
b3 = new JButton("Find Connection");
b4 = new JButton("Read File");
b5 = new JButton("Exit");
```

If I want to add Actionlistener to all 5 buttons, I'd have to do this 5 times for each button.

```
b1.addActionListener(this);
```

Is there a way to add actionlistener to all JButtons in the class in one line of code? Or even better add actionlistener to every component in the class?

Comment: What about a helper method that creates the button and assigns the listener?

Comment: The listener will do something different for each of these buttons. So you should have 5 different listeners anyway, instead of a single one.

Comment: I have an actionPerformed method that listens. In there I have 'Object src = event.getSource()'. Since src could be any component, all I have to do is use if statements to assign what each Jbutton does.So I thought, it would be easier if there was a way to add actionlistener to all components in my class.

Comment: @mountain5: why use a large `if, else if, else` chain instead of adhering to the single responsibility principle, and have one class do one thing, i.e. have a separate action listener for each button? This would be much cleaner.

Comment: Use the `JButton` constructor that takes an [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a loop that adds the listener to the buttons.

```
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    button[i].addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
}
```